# Condition with restriction choice of fields for interface

Tags: typescript

I would to make possibility of restriction, when selecting fields using interface.
There is interface:

```
interface ISchema {
  operator?: string;
  items?: ISchema[];
  condition?: string;
  conditionParam?: {};
}
```

Is it possible make, to when declaring a variable of this type:

```
let scheme = [] as ISchema;
```

and adding items, we had a choice only two elements:

**operator

condition**
If chosen **operator**, then show field **items**, but if choise **condition** then show field **conditionParam**

Comment: you can use let scheme = [] as any as ISchema;

Comment: As this question stands I don't understand what you're trying to ask.  My issues so far: • Do you really want `items` to be a single-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) or an array? • `scheme` is an array, not an `ISchema` object type; what are you trying to do here? • What do you mean by "show" in "show field"?  Is there some UI code involved with this?

Comment: Items it is array ISchema.  `What do you mean by "show" in "show field"?` show or autocomplete for IDE